# How to simplify nested if loop in node js querying

Tags: mysql, node.js

i need to simplify the below nested if loop code. How to do in node js.
also i need to make user based query calling in jscript itself instead of coding in ejs. How to display table data in chart using node js. is morris js chart is compatible for node js. if so how to parse the data into json from node js object from render function.

```
var moment = require('moment');
var currencyFormatter = require('currency-formatter');
var db = require('./db.js');

const siteTitle = "SalesFlow | Luftek";
const mainURL = "http://sales.luftek.in/";

var dquery = "SELECT COUNT(*) as pending FROM enquiries WHERE status = 'Processing';";
var listdquery = "SELECT * FROM enquiries WHERE status = 'Processing';";
var listsquery = "SELECT * FROM salesorder_b WHERE po_date >= NOW()- INTERVAL 14 DAY;";
var dsquery = "SELECT count(*) as recent_order FROM salesorder_b WHERE po_date >= NOW()- INTERVAL 14 DAY";
var hitratio = "SELECT ((SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM enquiries WHERE job_ref = (SELECT job_ref FROM salesorder_b where enquiries.job_ref = salesorder_b.job_ref) ) / (SELECT count(*) FROM enquiries))) * 100 as hitratio;";
var hitratioazeem = "SELECT ((SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM enquiries WHERE job_ref = (SELECT job_ref FROM salesorder_b where enquiries.job_ref = salesorder_b.job_ref) & sales_per = 'Azeem' ) / (SELECT count(*) FROM enquiries where sales_per = 'Azeem'))) * 100 as hitratioazeem;";
var hitratiosuresh = "SELECT ((SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM enquiries WHERE job_ref = (SELECT job_ref FROM salesorder_b where enquiries.job_ref = salesorder_b.job_ref) & sales_per = 'Suresh M' ) / (SELECT count(*) FROM enquiries where sales_per = 'Suresh M'))) * 100 as hitratiosuresh;";
var azeempendingenquiry = "SELECT COUNT(*) as pending FROM enquiries WHERE status = 'Processing' && sales_per = 'Azeem';";
var hitratiochart = "SELECT * FROM hitratio;";

exports.dboard = function (req, res) {

  if (req.user) {
    db.query(hitratio, function (err, hitresult) {
      if (err) { throw err; }
      else {
        db.query(dsquery, function (err, result1) {
          if (err) { throw err; }
          else {
            db.query(listdquery, function (err, plistresult) {
              if (err) { throw err; }
              else {
                db.query(listsquery, function (err, olistresult) {
                  if (err) { throw err; }
                  else {
                    db.query(dquery, function (err, result) {                
                      if (err) throw err;
                      else {
                        db.query(hitratioazeem, function (err, hitresultazeem) {
                          if (err) throw err;
                          else{
                            db.query(hitratiosuresh, function (err, hitresultsuresh) {
                              if (err) throw err;
                              else{
                                db.query(hitratiochart, function (err, hitresultchart) {
                                  if (err) throw err;
                                  else{
                                    res.render('pages/dashboard', {
                                      siteTitle: siteTitle,
                                      moment: moment,
                                      currencyFormatter: currencyFormatter,
                                      pageTitle: "Dashboard",
                                      hitresult1: hitresult[0],
                                      hitresult2: hitresultazeem[0],
                                      hitresult3: hitresultsuresh[0],
                                      sales: result1[0].recent_order,
                                      items: result[0].pending,
                                      hititems : hitresultchart,
                                      plists: plistresult,
                                      olists: olistresult,
                                      user: req.user
                                    });
                                  }
                                });
                              }
                            });
                          } 
                        });
                      }
                    })
                  }
                });
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
  else { res.redirect(mainURL); }

}
```

Comment: Please try to stick to one question/topic per post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "nested if loop" is commonly referred to as "callback hell" and there are various utility packages to deal with this. One popular one is `async`, which provides `async.parallel` for this particular use case:

```
async.parallel([
  (callback) => db.query(query1, callback),
  (callback) => db.query(query2, callback), 
  (callback) => db.query(query3, callback), 
], (err, results) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  res.render('pages/dashboard', {
    data1: results[0],
    data2: results[1],
    data3: results[2],
  }) 
})
```

To "render" JSON, check out Express' `res.json`.

With "user based query calling" I don't quite get what you are referring to. If you are talking about dynamically building SQL queries, I'd recommend a package such as `knex`.

Comment: Thank you! fantastic it is very useful. But some of the query is not calling by indexing please check my code below

Comment: async.parallel([
      (hitresult) => db.query(hitratio, hitresult),
      (result1) => db.query(dsquery, result1),
      (plistresult) => db.query(listdquery, plistresult),
      (olistresult) => db.query(listsquery, olistresult),
      (result) => db.query(dquery, result),
   ], (err, results) => {
      if (err) throw err;

      res.render('pages/dashboard', {
        pageTitle: "Dashboard",
        hitresult1: results[0],
        sales: results[1][0].recent_order,
        plists: results[2],
        olists: results[3],
        items: results[4][0].pending,
      })
    })

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by "not calling by indexing". Based on the SQL in your question, all queries are independent from each other. Also, in your code, you renamed the callback functions, which I would advise against. The way you named them, one would assume them to be values, but they are functions with a very specific set of arguments. Please check the docs for [`async.parallel`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel) and if you are not entirely sure what a "callback function" is, you should read up on that topic as well.

Comment: i have renamed the callback functions. but the query result is not displaying in ejs

Comment: still am not getting the result please refer the below code.

Comment: 'async.parallel([
      (callback) => db.query(hitratio, callback),
      (callback) => db.query(dsquery, callback),
      (callback) => db.query(listdquery, callback),
      (callback) => db.query(listsquery, callback),
      (callback) => db.query(dquery, callback),
    ], (err, results) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.render('', {
        hitresult1: results[0][0].hitratio,
        sales: results[1][0].recent_order,
        plists: results[2],
        olists: results[3],
        items: results[4][0].pending
      });
    });'

Comment: am getting result as undefined

Comment: `results` (the second parameter in the final callback function) is undefined? `async.parallel` should always pass an array, even if it's empty, so I don't know why that would happen. Apart from that, I just fixed an error in my code where I passed an empty string to `res.render`. You seem to have copied that. I also noticed that in your original code you passed a single object to `hitresult1`, whereas now you are passing the whole list (`results[0]` is the list, `results[0][0]` is the first element of that list).

Comment: what is the [0] [1] [2] of results. the hitresult1 is a value calculated for mysql query to display in ejs how to render in json.

Comment: `results` is an array containing the results of the functions passed to `async.parallel`. They are returned in the same order that you pass the functions, so `results[0]` is the value of the first query, `results[1]` is the value of the the second query, etc. If you'd rather use proper names instead of indices, you can also pass an object with functions instead of an array. Check out [the docs](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel) on how to that.

Comment: luftek.in/img/output2.png

Comment: is my code declaration are correct or wrong. it it is correct. in the docs the same is written. But i am not getting the exact answer. Please help me out

Comment: Thank you found the result... it should mention like results[0][0][0].object